# Writing simple kernel for my Android device

Tags: android, kernel, bootloader

I'm trying to develop a simple toy mobile operating system as a side project.

I'm trying to figure out how to boot a simple kernel and print "Hello World" to screen on an Android device.

Booting in x86-64 is fairly straightforward, but booting on an Android device is pretty complicated and I'm unable wrap around my head the booting process of an Android device.

Many different SOCs use different booting mechanisms, I am interested in learning to boot on a Qualcomm 855 soc, I use a OnePlus 7 pro, I would like to know if it's possible to boot up a simple assembly code that prints **Hello World** to the phone's display like the way we could on a normal computer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easy to write a simple boot that outputs the "hello world" on the debugging terminal (serial port), but to display something like that on the screen you need to write drivers for the display device, and render the characters, which is not very simple -- graphics device initialization and access might be quite involved.

Comment: Is it possible to write a device driver without the knowledge of the memory map of the device? Like without knowing where the I/O memory sits for the display?

Comment: @NithinRao sure, it's possible. but most likely it won't work =)